# Finding when parents married in Modesto, California, USA

Tags: 20th-century, marriage-records, california

I need to know what year and month my parents married in Modesto, California, USA.

How can I find out?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH. I've edited your post to remove the names of possibly-living people in line with our privacy policy (see https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  You're welcome to instate them if you can provide evidence either that they were both born > 100 years ago or evidence that they're both deceased.  In the meantime, I've also modified the question to ask for advice on how to search yourself for the information you need.

Answer (score 2):

The FamilySearch wiki page for [Stanislaus County, California genealogy](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/Stanislaus_County,_California_Genealogy#Marriage) lists the following sources for marriage records:

> - 1800 - 2007 - [California, United States Marriages](https://search.findmypast.com/search-world-records/united-states-marriages?state=ca%2ccalifornia) at FindMyPast — index $
> - 1850 - 1945 - [California Marriages, 1850-1945](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/1674735) at FamilySearch — index
> - 1850 - 1952 - [California, County Marriages, 1850-1952](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/1804002) at FamilySearch — index and images
> - 1854 - 1885 - [Western States Marriage Index](http://abish.byui.edu/specialCollections/westernStates/search.cfm) at BYU-Idaho
> - 1960 - 1985 - [California Marriage Index, 1960-1985](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/1949339) FamilySearch — index and images
> - [Early Stanislaus County Marriages](http://genealogytrails.com/cal/stanis/marriages.html) at Genealogy Trails

FamilySearch is free to use, but you'll need to create a free account to view many of the records.

Answer (score 1):

A cursory search of the webpages for Modesto and Stanislaus County brought me to the County Clerk-Recorder, where you can [order copies](http://www.stancounty.com/clerkrecorder/recorders/how-to-order-copies.shtm) of vital records. It doesn't give an e-mail addres, but a phone number is listed and this could be first step to confirm that they do in fact have your parent's marriage certificate.

I can't say for sure about the US or California, but generally these sorts of documents are indexed by name, so it should be possible for them to find the record even if you don't have the exact date.